# Jquery function stopped working

Tags: php, jquery, json, httpwebrequest

I have been using this script for a while and suddenly it just stopped working and returns the error message.  I cannot find any errors with the code and the php page echoes valid json.   Please if anyone can find an error or something wrong with this code let me know.  I am using the same script other places just fine.

Go to: 
http://ab-mobile-apps.com/app/grotto/index.html 
then click random drink to see live.  Clicking the error message will call the function again.

Thanks ahead.

```
function loadData() {                              
    var output = $('#output');
    var drinkImageOutput = $('#drinkImage');
    var drinkIngredientOutput = $('#drinkIngredient');
    var drinkNameOutput = $('#drinkName');

    output.text('');

    $.ajax({

        url: 'http://ab-mobile-apps.com/grototest/index.php',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        jsonp: 'jsoncallback',
        timeout: 10000,
        success: function(data, status){
        $.each(data, function(i,item){
        var landmark = 
            '<div id="drinkImage"><img src="' + drinkImg + '" width="15%" /></div>' + 
            '<div id="drinkName">' + drinkName + '</div>' +
            '<div id="dringIngredient">' + dringIngredient + '</div>';


        output.append(landmark);
        });
        },
        error: function(){
        output.text('There was an error loading the data.');
        }
    });            
}
```

Comment: Use the debugger in Chrome to step through the code...

Comment: Upped your comment Kris and to further elaborate, in Chrome dev tools (press F12 to open), go to the Network tab... in there you'll see the AJAX request and find out what is being returned, from there you should be able to debug your script

Comment: I appreciate your responses.  Prior to posting I debugged the script many times with chrome and the ajax call appears to get skipped.  Have you tried it with the url I posted.  Please do and give feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your request returns JSON not JSONP.
Try:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://ab-mobile-apps.com/grototest/index.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    timeout: 10000,
    success: function(data, status){
    $.each(data, function(i,item){
    var landmark = 
        '<div id="drinkImage"><img src="' + item.url + '" width="15%" /></div>' + 
        '<div id="drinkName">' + item.sname + '</div>' +
        '<div id="dringIngredient">' + item.ingredients + '</div>';


    output.append(landmark);
    });
    },
    error: function(){
    output.text('There was an error loading the data.');
    }
});
```